# identify product by name

Tags: database, database-design

I have an application which deals with ordering some items. The items are stored in a products table.
For some of the products the order process and details are different. 
So i need to identify these by name and have a different ui.
Would storing the identifying information as boolean fields in table be appropriate

**products(table)**:

is_abc = true,

is_xyz = false etc

or use a file based approach?

**products_id.txt**

abc_product_id: 1

xyz_product_id: 2

Would be interested to know if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally recommend using attributes in the database to describe the products.  You could use Boolean values, but let's assume for a moment that you have two processes now and that may change to three or four in the future.  In a situation like that a Boolean will not work.  I would consider using a look-up table to define the varying processes and use the id of each process in the products table.  So for example:

Look-Up Table may contain rows like this:
    ProcessID = 1, ProcessName = "Some Process"
    ProcessID = 2, ProcessName = "A Second Process"
    ProcessID = 3, ProcessName = "Third process used"

Then in your products table you could have a column for ProcessID that would contain the ProcessID from the look-up table.

You could do something similar with details and have a ProductDetails table that defined these and provided a foreign key to the main products table.

Comment: There are actually 20+ products to be identified by name. Hence lookup looks better. Some of the products would be mapped to single process i suppose a group name column would handle this?